# I keep getting errors when merging upstream (git)

Tags: git, github, merge

Unfortunately after merging to the upstream repo I cleared the console and can't remember the exact error message. I can't reproduce the error since `git merge upstream/master
Already up-to-date.`

That said when running `git merge upstream/master` trying to merge with (web starter kit) I get an error https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/commit/446845e954969468ae7fb5f93cdb87d3c1ca4c81 this commit for example will merge like this in my local project.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
=======
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">
>>>>>>> upstream/master
```

I assume a few things, but it seems it wants to possibly preserve my code, not sure though. Overall the merge wasn't bad, it added new files and such, so it seems it did it's job for the most part.

I would just like to figure out how to make this merge a bit more clean, so I don't have to manually clean things up.

I hope I gave enough detail, I will try and reproduce the error.

**Additional**: This is not a fork of WSK, this is a just a clone that I manually added a remote to WSK called upstream, and I fetch/merge the updates whenever.

Comment: You are getting a conflicts - it means both upstream and your local repo have changes in the same place. Use any mergetool (e.g meld) and commit clean code after resolving conflicts. You can set your default mergetool in gitconfig or just run `git mergetool -t <mergetool_of_your_choice>`

Comment: Okay thanks for that, I will refer back to this when I am ready to merge to the upstream repo. I just cleaned all the errors and don't want to merge or even think about it right now. If this works well for you you can post a semi-detailed answer and we can close this.